# Errors on gitlab CI/CD job - "bash: line 122: npm: command not found"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gitlab, cicd

```
image: ubuntu:18.04 
before_script:
  - npm install
cache:
  paths:
  - node_modules

unit-test:
  tags:
    - test
  image: node:16.16.0
  script:
    - echo "Run unit testing"
    - npm run test
    - echo "Test successfully!"
```

This is what I wrote in gitlab CI/CD and I got an error said "bash: line 122: npm: command not found." I run a gitlab-runner in docker, and someone please help me. Thank you! (I am really new to the gitlab and docker stuff, and sorry for asking dumb questions......)

Comment: You are using base ubuntu image which doesn't have npm installed in it. Either you use base image with npm pre-installed or in before script prior to executing `npm install`, add a step for installing npm.

Comment: `$ install npm
install: missing destination file operand after 'npm'
Try 'install --help' for more information.` This is what I got once I typed `install npm`, and I just wonder how to do it or if there is any tutorials about this. Sorry for asking these dumb questions, and hope you have a great day!

Comment: Why don't you use the image specified in `unit_test` instead of ubuntu.

Comment: Or you said I can add an image with npm pre-installed, do you know what are those? I am working on a test project so any recommendations are fine since I can change it to whatever I want.

Comment: Use `node:16.16.0` instead of `ubuntu:18.04`

Comment: This what I changed to `cache:
  paths:
  - node_modules

unit-test:
  tags:
    - test
  image: node:16.16.0
  script:
    - npm install
    - echo "Run unit testing"
    - npm run test
    - echo "Test successfully!"` And it still doesnt work......

Comment: What about your first line that you have mentioned in the question? Change that to node image as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you used a Shared or Specific runner?

In the case of shared,
What are the tags of the shared runner?

In the case of the specific,
Can I see the steps you go through when registering your runner?